# Remove old data from website table after Fire-base updates

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm using Fire-base to update a website table. It works great in adding data from database to the table in real time. The only setback is that after data is deleted from the database it is still reflecting in the website tables unless or until reloading the page, which i was trying to avoid.

At the moment i have tried using **child_removed** to see if it responds to any command but i'm not having much luck with it.

```
// web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
...
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var database = firebase.database().ref().child('basketball');

//if a child is added add to webiste table
database.on('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();
            content +='<tr>';

            content +='<td class=" align-middle text-center">';
            content +='<span class="user-initials bg-success-light25 text-success">FB</span>';
            content +='</td>';

            content +='<td class="align-middle">';
            content +='<small class="text-muted weight-300">' + val.sport + '</small>';
            content +='<div><a id="calccall" href="#" class="weight-400">' + val.home_team + ' vs ' + val.away_team + '</a></div>';
            content +='</td>';

            content +='<td class="align-middle">';
            content +='<div class="weight-400">' + val.market + '</div>';
            content +='</td>';

            content +='<td class="align-middle"><span class="material-icons align-middle md-18 text-success">expand_less</span>' + val.arbitrage + '%</td>';
            content +='<td class="align-middle text-right">' + val.game_time + '</td>';

            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#test_table').append(content)
    }
});
```

The expected result is removing of rows from the website table once they are removed in the fire-base database

Comment: Your code is using the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and not [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). I updated the tags to match. While both databases are part of Firebase, they each have their own API, documentation, and their own tag here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could use `$('#test_table').empty()` before you append the new content?

Comment: Hi @sandrooco that works perfect, massive thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the data under `basketball` changes, your callback gets called again by Firebase with a new snapshot of all data under `basketball`. In this method you're rebuilding the entire HTML contents, and then *append* it to the table with:

```
$('#test_table').append(content)
```

So if you're starting out with 3 child nodes in your table, you're building HTML for that and add it to the table, so that it becomes:

```
row1
row2
row3
```

Now if you remove the last row, your callback fires again and adds the remaining data to the end of the table, so you end up with:

```
row1
row2
row3
row1
row2
```

To only show the latest state, you need to *replace* the existing HTML. The easiest change is to call:

```
$('#test_table').html(content)
```

With this code the output will look like this after the second time your callback fires:

```
row1
row2
```

Comment: works like a charm. massive thanks. Still learning more on fire-base and manipulating its contents